# the meaning of "will have to do"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I don't understand the meaning of ***"will have to do"*** in the following paragraph. What does it mean?

> "However, whatever significant portion of Earth's satellite will be visible Sunday, July 21, **will have to do** for everyone joining in at the Hamptons Full Moon Fest shindig starting at 6 p.m."
>
> -- [Article *"Hamptons Full Moon Fest at Gurney’s Inn"*, newsday.com (July 21 2013)](http://long-island.newsday.com/bars-and-clubs/lol-1.1887675/hamptons-full-moon-fest-at-gurney-s-inn-1.5736159)

Comment: Mike has answered the question below. I found the meaning difficult to get on first reading because of the commas in the date. It would have been far more straightforward  without any punctuation there.

Comment: @tunny the commas are correct for that way of referring to dates.

Answer (score 8):

In this context, "will have to do" means "will have to be acceptable, since we have no other choice".  When someone says this, it implies that this outcome might be imperfect; however, other factors constrain a better outcome.

Comment: Mike, I don't know why, but "will have to be acceptable" sounds ungrammatical to my (non-native) ear.

Comment: "Will have to be acceptable" is perfectly acceptable.  :)  It has an implied meaning of "will have to be considered acceptable" or "taken as acceptable."  Perhaps "will have to suffice" is a bit more explicit.

Comment: @bobrhodes, regarding "will have to suffice", good critique...

Comment: The problem with "will have to be acceptable" is that it mixes two different mutually exclusive concepts. Acceptableness implies a choice and "have to" implies there isn't a choice. As stated above "will have to suffice" or "will have to be sufficient" is a better wording. That said "I have to accept" is a commonly used phrase.